# Cannot import 'etree' from 'lxml'

Tags: installation, pip, lxml, elementtree

I have installed lxml on my Windows machine using

```
pip install lxml
```

However, if I run

```
from lxml import etree
```

or

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
```

I get

```
cannot import name 'etree' from 'lxml' (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\lxml\__init__.py)
```

I have uninstalled and reinstalled lxml many times through pip and it installs successfully every time. I can see folders lxml and lxml-4.6.2.dist-info getting installed in site-packages every time I reinstall. I don't have any lxml.py files in this directory either.

Answer (score 0):

Do you also have Anaconda installed ? If you have both Python and Anaconda installed, there are two directories for the site-packages (one for Python and another for Ananconda), which could cause an error when trying to import.

You can try the following steps below and then run your program again:

1. Uninstall Anaconda from your machine
2. pip uninstall lxml
3. pip install lxml